# Get JNDI Names from DataSource after lookup

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jndi, lookup

What I want to achieve is to get the JNDI name as a String from a DataSource object.

I have the following code to get the DataSource:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/dataPool");
```

My `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` where JNDI name is set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.6/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>AdminBean</ejb-name>
        <stateless-session-descriptor></stateless-session-descriptor>
        <resource-description>
            <res-ref-name>dataPool</res-ref-name>
            <jndi-name>jdbc/CARGAS</jndi-name>
        </resource-description>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

So, when I get the `ds` object actually I can see the JndiNames but I cannot find the way to get it out from it:

[image: As you can see]

My first guess was to do something like `ds.getJndiNames` but I only have the folowing options:

[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Why do you even want this? Btw: with the debugger you look into the implementation, not the interface... you can always downcast, but do you really want to?

Comment: I want to do this because I want to split the way to obtain the ds depending on server. This code is shared by WebSphere and Weblogic, and WebSphere likes the `java:comp/env/dataPool` whereas that Weblogic wants the jndi name `jdbc/CARGAS`

Answer (score 0):

Ok!

So at the end I use Reflection to achieve what I want to.

Here my solution:

```
public String getJndiName() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/dataPool");
        Method method = ds.getClass().getMethod("getJNDINames");
        String[] jndi = (String[])method.invoke(ds);
       return jndi[0];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpfull for anyone else in the future :-)

Comment: Hi, what package is Method ??